# $_GET not working after jQuery .load()

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery .load() to reload a div that I ran a MySQL query in. Part of the query takes a value from a variable, which itself is set by a $_GET. When I .load() that div again, the $_GET loses value, as does any variable that was holding the $_GET value.

My code was somewhat like this:

```
<div id="foo">
<?php
     $var = $_GET['p'];
     //sql query
     echo $var;
     //echo sql query
 ?>
 </div>
```

With `#foo` being the div that is re-load()ed with jQuery.

If I hardcode, for example, `$var = 7`, the page in question *will work*. So I know it's not a problem elsewhere.

Any help?

Comment: can you past your jQuery load call, because I think that you didn't update your QueryString when div updated.

Comment: Are you passing the parameter value back when you call ".load()"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to pass your parameters to the `load()` call as well. The original requests parameters will not be stored anywhere. You will likely need something like

```
$('#foo').load('my/url?p=<? $_GET['p'] ?>');
```

I have no idea if that's the proper PHP syntax, but you get the idea. You will also likely want to encode that value for the query string.

Answer (score 1):

@jcm

```
$('#foo').load('my/url?p=<?php echo $_GET['p'] ?>');
```

short hand openings are not enabled by default and you must echo or print what you what to output

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content').load('myfolder/script_file.php?id=123');
```